# how can I add IPN variable in database Like POSTURL and USER ID Wordpress PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, paypal

Currently I have integrate the **paypal** with my site and 
this is working after successful payment.
I have set IPN so that this can be update in my Database. But in database only few variable are inserted like `PAYMENT_ID, Payment_Status,TXN_ID, Country_Code`.
This is code for inserting this data in database.

---

```
//Payment data
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $payment_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $currency_code = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];

    //Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
    $prevPayment = $db->query("SELECT payment_id FROM payments WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");
    if($prevPayment->num_rows > 0){
        exit();
    }else{
        //Insert tansaction data into the database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO payments(item_number,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status) VALUES('".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')");
    }
```

---

I want to add User id and PostURL of the Post from where this payment is made.

Or some any unique identifier so that 
I can cross which user have make which post payment .

Comment: You can use the [`custom` variable](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) to store extra information such as your user id and post URL prior to submitting to Paypal.

Comment: Can you please specify how can i use because i have try this
and in HTML variable i have use  "custom" variable but how to call that in IPN file
so that i
 can insert that in my database.
is this format will work 
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
@Mikey

Comment: It depends on what you are doing to get to the Paypal checkout page. If you are using their generated form, you could pass information in `custom` variable using a hidden field as done in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7188586/1022914).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mikey